# Tess4j error : UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: windows, tesseract, tess4j

I am trying to use tess4j for my project.
I have looked around in the forum and placed the dlls in the project. also the tessdata folder is in place.

I am getting a : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.`

Can someone please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need install windows vs,the Tesseract DLLs were built with VS2013 and therefore depend on the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages,if you want know which version,please check tess4j.jar with readme.html file.good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add the below **VM argument** to your Run Configuration in case you are using eclipse.
You will have to make sure that the dll files are in the project root folder. I have just named it dll. You will also have to replace your_project_name in the line below with the actual name of your project:

```
Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/your_project_name}/dlls
```